# Exercise 6(d), Section 3.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be the linear operator on $R^2$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2)=(-x_2,x_1)$.
>
> (d) Prove that if $B$ is any ordered basis for $R^2$ and $[T]_B = A$, then $A_{12}\cdot A_{21}\neq 0$.

**My attempt:** Let $B=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$, where $\alpha_1=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\alpha_2=(y_1,y_2)$, be basis of $V$. Assume towards contradiction, $A_{12}\cdot A_{21}= 0$. Then $A_{12}=0$ or $A_{21}=0$. WLOG, assume $A_{21}=0$. So $T(\alpha_1)$ $=T((x_1,x_2))$ $=(-x_2,x_1)$ $=A_{11}\cdot \alpha_1+0\cdot \alpha_2$ $=A_{11}\cdot (x_1,x_2)$ $=(A_{11}\cdot x_1,A_{11}\cdot x_2)$. So $-x_2=A_{11}\cdot x_1$ and $x_1=A_{11}\cdot x_2$. Substitute $x_1=A_{11}\cdot x_2$ in $-x_2=A_{11}\cdot x_1$, we get $-x_2$ $=A_{11}\cdot (A_{11}\cdot x_2)$ $=A_{11}^2\cdot x_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $A_{11}^2\cdot x_2+x_2=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $(A_{11}^2+1)\cdot x_2=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_2=0$. Similarly, substitute $x_2$ $=-(A_{11}\cdot x_1)$ $=-A_{11} \cdot x_1$ in $x_1=A_{11}\cdot x_2$, we get $x_1=0$. So $\alpha_1=(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$. Which implies $B=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ is dependent. Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $A_{12}\cdot A_{21}\neq 0 $. **Is my  proof correct?**

Comment: If $A_{12}=0$, then $\alpha_2=(y_1,y_2)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative : $T:\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$  definited by $$T(x_1,x_2)=(-x_2,x_1)$$

is not [triangularizable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) i.e there is no basis $B$ w.r.to which $[T]_B$ is triangular. Hence off diagonal entries are non zero and so that their product is also non zero.